# Material-UI: Removing linkOperator from data-grid

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

is it possible to remove the linkOperator UI entirely from the filter panel?

Material-UI: Moving pagination to the top of table? It is the "Operators" menu here. I have done this but can I programmatically do it?

```
      ".MuiDataGridFilterForm-linkOperatorSelect": {
        display: "none !important",
      },
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the **latest Material-UI library (v5)**, you will have to use this code below because the properties have changed since the last answer here.

```
  slotProps={{
    filterPanel: {
        logicOperators: [],
      },
  }}
```

You could read more about it [here](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/filtering/#customize-the-filter-panel-content).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to remove linkOperators by this

```
componentsProps={{
    filterPanel: {
        linkOperators: [],
      },
  }}
```